# Test server for release pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Forgive me for asking a stupid question. I am from IT Infrastructure background & have been asked to create CI/CD pipelines based on my recent learnings on DevOps.

We have couple of applications whose source code is currently in TFS 2013 & those apps are written in ASP.NET C# language. Now, requirement is to migrate the source code from TFS to Azure Repos (Azure DevOps services) & further create a CI/CD pipeline.

Now for demo purposes, customer is asking us to do the deployment (i.e. Release pipeline) on a test server which is a plain windows 2012 OS without any SQL & IIS for both of these applications. Is that possible & how could we achieve the results to confirm release pipeline is funcioning properly?

In my opinion, it wont work as there is no application infra/configuration done for those applications on that plain test server. I guess we actually need a ready dev/stage environment which is replica of production to do the testing of release pipeline for those applications. Am I correct?

Just need expert advise for confirmation so I communicate the same to customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps Pipelines use an agent to perform the deployments. You can run the agent entirely in the cloud when deploying to Azure resources. You can also install an agent locally. [Follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and scroll down to read about self-hosted agents. This is how you can deploy to your test instance from the pipeline.

Now, what you deploy there may require additional software be installed. You say it's an application in C#. Cool. Now, what's it do? Is it a windows program? Then just having the server there, with an agent installed, is all you need. Is it a web program? Then, yeah, it's going to need an IIS (or whatever) instance available somewhere to deploy to. Is it a database program? Then, yeah, it's going to need a database instance to deploy to. There's nothing magical about having a VM or a machine somewhere. All the same rules have to apply. There has to be an OS, drives, memory, and yes, supporting services depending on the needs of the application.

However, using a local machine instead of a hosted one, that works fine. Just follow the instructions in the link above.